# Centering large image in small div with overflow visible

Tags: html, css

I want to centre a banner image of size 1920x225px in a div 960px wide.
the problem occuring is that the image is not in the centre as it starts from top left.
Heres an image to describing the issue
http://tinypic.com/r/scco0m/5

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
background-position: center center;
```

on your background image.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: i dont want it to be a background image. its an aimage inside a div<>

Comment: Okay, was just wondering because your question is tagged wit "CSS". I set up a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c7VDh/ is that what you mean?

Comment: its a web banner of 1920px x 225 px. i want the image to be in the centre even if it is viewed on desktops with a smaller screen size

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention  here, how  you adding he image in a website

if you are giving background image

give css like this `background:url(../image.jpg) center center no-repeat;`

If you don't want background image just give `max-width:100%` for that image

---

New Answer.

You need to give `position:relative` for the div having width:960px

and for the image add like this

```
img{position:absolute; left:50px; top:20px; z-index:999}
```

You can change the Left and top value according to your Wish

Comment: i am using an img tag. i dont want it to be in the background

Comment: @aspiring_web_developer u canot make center the image by giving <img /> tag. `max-width:100%` for that image will work fine

Comment: i dont want the image to re adjust itself for small screens.. i have posted a link in the question. can you have a look at it?http://tinypic.com/r/scco0m/5

Comment: i tried that. Now the contents of the lower div are overlapping on the image ;-(